# Css driven sticky footer in HTML page shows in top of the page in some machines while in the bottom of others

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

Here's my CSS for the footer i'm using in my website http://www.sremavision.com

```
#footer_container 
{ 
    background:#eee; 
    border:1px solid #666; 
    bottom:0; 
    height:30px; 
    left:0;  
    position:fixed; 
    width:100%; 
    border: 1; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
#footer 
{ 
    line-height:30px; 
    z-index: 10000; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center; 
    color: black;  
}
```

What goes wrong is that the resulting footer stays on top in some machines accessing the website, while its okay on others, even if the browsers used are same, (even browsers with same versions).

Comment: Link is wrong, please correct it.

Comment: Can you explain what you need exactly?